# Why can't I call methods of Long objects inside a SimpleEntry child class?

Tags: java, long-integer, comparable

```
   public class PriorityQueueEntry<TimedTask, Long> extends AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<TimedTask, Long> implements Comparable<PriorityQueueEntry<TimedTask, Long>> {

        public PriorityQueueEntry(TimedTask key, Long value) {
            super(key, value);            
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(PriorityQueueEntry<TimedTask, Long> o) {
            ((Long)getValue()).compareTo((Long)o.getValue());
        }
    }
```

NetBeans tells me that it can't find the compareTo method. Why can't I do this?

Comment: Yes, it's mine. The cast is a typo. I'll edit it.

Comment: If `o.getValue()` returns an object which can be cast to `Long`, do it as `getValue().compareTo((Long)o.getValue())`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
public class PriorityQueueEntry<TimedTask, Long> ...
```

you will define a class with two generic arguments named `TimedTask` and `Long`. These are not the actual classes you know, but are generic arguments, which *happens* to have the same name as the classes `TimedTask` and `Long`. Depending on what you want, you might want to remove these generic arguments or rename them to common names like `E`, `K` or `V`.